# Clean up directory and file artifacts

Tags: beginner, python-3.x, file-system

I have some directories with artifacts in them, and I want to clean them up by deleting them. The requirements are:

- Keep the 3 most recent directories
- Keep only one snapshot folder
- Keep only one rc folder
- Delete everything else
- The print commands should be written to a log file for posterity

This code is in the root of a Linux Server and it will be run every morning.

Lib import
In this case we only have basic libraries, so we do not need to raise the environment first

```
import os, sys, glob
import datetime
import re
import shutil
import subprocess

from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment
from xml.dom import minidom
```

Environment

```
env = 'cd environment/bin/activate'
```

PATHs

```
mypath = '/home/directories' #test
path_log = '/home/directories/delete-versions.log' #test
```

Gobal VAR

```
percent = 50
versions = 3
snapshots = 1
rcs = 1
```

Security exclude directories

```
exclude = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

PREP

```
def start_var():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return now

def raise_environment(env):
    try:
        subprocess.run(env, shell=True)
        print('Environment raised')
    except:
        print('Error: Environment not found. Please, run again manualy')

def info_log(path_log, message):
  with open(path_log,'a') as f:
      f.write(f'\n{message}\n')


###############################
######### Check space #########
###############################      
def bash_commands(command):
    ocup = str(subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True))
    ocup = int(str(re.findall('\d+', ocup)).replace("['", "").replace("']", ""))
    return ocup   

###############################
######### Acquisition #########
###############################
def getting_routes(mypath, exclude):  
    # Getting the list of the directories I am going to iter
    roots = routes = []
    # Let outside the exclude routes
    roots = os.listdir(mypath)
    roots = [mypath + '/' + x for x in roots if x not in exclude]
    # Looking for directories with more than one version and with xx.xx.xx
    # When I found a version directory, i get the up route
    for root in roots:
        for (dirpath, _, _) in os.walk(root):
            find = re.findall('\d+\.\d+\.\d+', dirpath)
            if len(find) >= 1:
                directory = str(re.findall('^(.+)\/[^\/]+$', dirpath)).replace("['", "").replace("']", "")
                if directory not in routes:
                    routes.append(directory)
    print(f'Routes ready')
    info_log(path_log, 'Routes ready')
    return(routes)

############################
######### Wrangling #########
############################
def delete(path, delete_time):
    if len(delete_time) > 0:
        for item in delete_time:
            #shutil.rmtree(path + '/' + item, ignore_errors=True)
            #I want to know if I delete or not the directories, so I do not use ignore_erros and I create a try/except
            try:
                shutil.rmtree(path + '/' + item)
                message08 = ' Deleting: '+ path  + '/' + item
                print(f'\n{message08}\n')
                info_log(path_log, message08)
            except:
                message09 = item + ' read only. We do not delete'
                print(f'\n{message09}\n')
                info_log(path_log, message08)
                
                
def prettify(elem):
    #Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element.
    rough_string = ElementTree.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ") # For each element
    

def create_modify_xmls(path, all, keep_directories, keep_snapshots):
          now = str(datetime.datetime.now())
          top = Element('metadata')
          child1 = SubElement(top, 'Id')
          child1.text = '.'.join(path.replace(mypath + '/', '').split('/')[:-1])
          child2 = SubElement(top, 'Id02')
          child2.text = path.split('/')[-1]
          child3 = SubElement(top, 'versioning')
          current_group = SubElement(child3, 'versions')
          lastupdated = SubElement(child3, 'lasUpdated')
          lastupdated.text = now
          # metadata-local
          for a in all:
              version = SubElement(current_group, 'version')
              version.text = a
          xml = str(prettify(top))
          with open(path + '/-local.xml','w') as f:
              f.write(xml)
          # metadata-releases
          for k in keep_directories:
              version = SubElement(current_group, 'version')
              version.text = k
          xml = str(prettify(top))
          with open(path + '/-releases.xml','w') as f:
              f.write(xml)
          for s in keep_snapshots:
              version = SubElement(current_group, 'version')
              version.text = s
          xml = str(prettify(top))
          with open(path + '/-snapshots.xml','w') as f:
              f.write(xml)

############################
######### Analysis #########
############################
def find_directories_snapshots_rcs(routes, snapshots, rcs, versions):           
    for path in routes:# List of routes to find
        files = os.listdir(path) #List with all inside path
        snapshots = keep_snapshorts = delete_snapshots = []
        rcs = keep_rcs = delete_rcs = xmls = []
        all_directories = keep_directories = delete_directories = []
        message03 = '----------------------------------------------------\nGo to:'+ path +'\n----------------------------------------------------'
        print(f'\n{message03}\n')
        info_log(path_log, message03)
        for f in files: # For each element
            is_directory = os.path.isdir(path + '/' + f)
            if is_directory == True:
                all_directories.append(f)
        all_directories.sort(reverse=True)
        message04 = ' All directories: '+ str(all_directories)
        print(f'\n{message04}\n') 
        info_log(path_log, message04)
        # We are going to find here snapshot, redhat and RCs
        # Everything else is going to be treated as the same
        snapshots = [w for w in all_directories if 'SNAPSHOT' in w]
        snapshots.sort(reverse=True)
        if len(snapshots) > 0:
            keep_snapshots = snapshots[:snapshots]
            delete_snapshots = snapshots[snapshots:]
            message05 = ' All snapshots:'+ str(snapshots) +'\n Snapshots to keep: ' + str(keep_snapshots) + '\
            \n Snapshots to delete: ' + str(delete_snapshots)
            print(f'\n{message05}\n')
            info_log(path_log, message05)
        # Now RCs
        rcs = [w for w in all_directories if 'RC' in w]
        rcs.sort(reverse=True)
        if len(rcs) > 0:   
            keep_rcs = rcs[:rcs]
            delete_rcs = rcs[rcs:]
            message06 = ' All RCs:'+ str(rcs) + '\n RCs to keep: ' + str(keep_rcs) + '\n RCs to delete: '+ str(delete_rcs)
            print(f'\n{message06}\n')
            info_log(path_log, message06)
        # Now redhats
        # We want to delete all redhats
        redhats = [w for w in all_directories if 'redhat' in w]   
        # Preparamos
        all_directories = [x for x in all_directories if x not in snapshots]
        all_directories = [x for x in all_directories if x not in rcs]
        all_directories = [x for x in all_directories if x not in redhats]           
        keep_directories = all_directories[:versions]
        delete_directories = all_directories[versions:] + redhats
        delete_time = delete_snapshots + delete_rcs + delete_directories
        all = keep_directories + keep_rcs + keep_snapshots
        all.sort()
        message07 = ' Directories:'+ str(all_directories) +'\n Directories to keep: '+ str(keep_directories) +'\n Directories to delete: '+ str(delete_directories)
        print(f'\n{message07}\n')
        info_log(path_log, message07)
        # Now is when delete for real
        delete(path, delete_time)
        # Create XML
        create_modify_xmls(path, all, keep_directories, keep_snapshots)

def duration(start):
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    duration = end - start
    message10 = 'Duracion del proceso: '+ str(duration)
    print(f'\n{message10}\n')
    info_log(path_log, message10)

#################################################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    raise_environment(paradigma_env)
    start = start_var()
    message01 = '--------------------------------- Ejecution ' + str(start)+' ------------------'
    info_log(path_log, message01)
    command01 = "df -k | grep root | awk '{print $5}'"
    ocup01 = bash_commands(command01)
    if ocup01 < percent:
        # If the ocupation of the server ies less tahan the percent we did, out and log
        message02 = 'Ocu is ' + str(ocup01) + '%, less than '+ str(percent) +'%.\
        \nOut'
        print(f'\n{message02}\n')
        info_log(path_log, message02)
    else:
        # It the ocupation is high or equal to percent, start
        message03 = 'Ocup is '+ str(ocup01) +'%, higher or equal to '+ str(percent) +'%.\nStart delete process'
        print(f'\n{message03}\n')
        info_log(path_log, message03)
        routes = getting_routes(mypath, exclude)
        find_directories_snapshots_rcs(routes, snapshots, rcs, versions)  
    duration(start)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stream of consciousness review from top-to-bottom.

- You should make sure you're adhering to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and general styling guides. I like to use [Black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to format my code
- `start_var` just obfuscates `datetime.datetime.now()` and doesn't need to exist. `duration` is similar. I honestly would rather see this wrapped up in your info logger class (see below) - have it log start/end time on `__enter__` and `__exit__`.
- I don't see the point of `raise_environment` - you could just do `os.chdir(path)`

#### `info_log`

I don't like that this repeatedly opens a file everytime you need it, and now everything needs to know/assume the `path_log` variable everywhere. Instead, I would prefer that you construct a logger object and pass that around. This also lets you avoid the messy duplication of printing and logging.

I would do something like this (untested):

```
import sys
class InfoLogger:

    def __init__(self, log_file, print_loc=sys.stdout):
        self.log_file = log_file
        self.print_here = print_loc

    def __enter__(self):
        self.open_file = open(self.log_file, 'a')

    def __exit__(self):
        self.open_file.close()

    def log_message(message):
        to_write = f"\n{message}\n"
        self.open_file.write(to_write)
        self.print_here.write(to_write)
```

This lets you do something like this:

```
with InfoLogger(path_log) as logger:
    getting_routes(base_path, exclude_list, logger)
    # etc
```

If you don't do this, please at least factor your print statements into this as well to avoid duplication of formatting.

#### `getting_routes`

Throughout this function, you use low-level `os` APIs, or you do direct string operations. In Python 3.4+, you can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) instead.

A few additional notes:

- `re.findall('\d+\.\d+\.\d+')` is pretty magic, and doesn't actually get used (we don't care about the versions, we just want to check if they exist). I would probably wrap this in a helper function
- `directory = str(re.findall('^(.+)\/[^\/]+$', dirpath)).replace("['", "").replace("']", "")` is not what you want - you want `re.findall('pattern').join(",")` (I don't know why - this line doesn't make sense to me, which is a good indicator that you need a helper function, to split it onto multiple lines, and maybe some comments)
- `if directory not in routes` can get very expensive for long lists. Consider using a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) instead

I ended up with something like this:

```
def getting_routes(mypath, exclude):
    routes = set()
    get_routes_recursive(mypath, exclude, routes)
    return routes

def get_routes_recursive(base_path, exclude_list, routes):
    for path in base_path.iterdir():
        if path.name in exclude_list:
            continue
        if path.is_dir():
            if is_versioned_path(path.name):
                add_all_children(path, exclude_list, routes)
            else:
                get_routes_recursive(path, exclude_list, routes)

def add_all_children(base_path, exclude_list, routes):
    routes.update(
        path
        for path in base_path.glob("**\*")
        if path.name not in exclude_list
    )            

def is_versioned_path(path):
    return re.findall(r"\d+\.\d+\.\d+", path.name)
```

#### `delete`

You should not use length to identify non-empty lists (this applies elsewhere) - instead, you can just do `if my_list`. Even better, if the only thing you want to do is loop, then just loop - it won't do anything if empty.

When you handle exceptions, you should never use a bare `except:` - always catch the specific list of exceptions you want to do something with.

Additionally, for safety, you should avoid just concatenating paths. Instead, you can use the [slash operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators): `shutil.rmtree(path / item)` (this assumes you're using `pathlib`.

I didn't notice it until here, but you don't need a unique `messageX` variable for each message (I don't think you need them at all - see `InfoLogger` above). Just use `message` (or whatever) each time.

#### `create_modify_xmls`

This line is very suspect:

```
child1.text = '.'.join(path.replace(mypath + '/', '').split('/')[:-1])
```

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do - I *think* you're trying to remove your root path, and then get the path without the final component? There are a number of [APIs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#accessing-individual-parts) that I think will work better for this. Specifically, you would do something like this (just guessing):

```
mypath = Path("/home/directories")
childpath = Path(<something>)
if childpath.is_relative_to(mypath):
    mypath_parents_length = len(mypath.parents)
    child1.text = ".".join(
        parent.name
        for i, parent in enumerate(childpath.parents)
        if i >= mypath_parents_length
    )
else:
    child1.text = ".".join(childpath.parents.name)
```

Similarly, `child2.text = path.split('/')[-1]` should become `child2.text = path.name`

#### `find_directories_snapshots_rcs`

Again, this will be cleaner with `pathlib` instead of `os`.

There's a lot of code here, and I'm hitting review fatigue, so I won't touch on everything:

This pattern (`some_list = list[:list]`) doesn't work - you can't slice using a list, unless there is something I'm missing about how you've defined this.

I suspect that you'll be better off not using list comprehensions and just looping over `all_directories` once to accumulate your other lists.

Avoid using the names of builtins (`all`) as variable names

#### Final thoughts

I don't think you need to use subprocess (`"df -k | grep root | awk '{print $5}'"`); I think you can just use [`os.statvfs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.statvfs) (I'm on a Windows machine, so I can't test).